# How to indent all lines underneath a newly created environment

Tags: formatting, indentation, parindent

In the following, and every time I use the command `prayerheading`, every line immediately following that heading is not indented and the following line is indented.

I would rather have it all indented. Hence, I'm using the `indentfirst` package but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newcommand{\prayerheading}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
  \vspace{-1em}
      \indent\scshape\Large\textcolor{black}{#1}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\prayerheading{Evening Troparia-Tone 6}
 Have mercy on us, O Lord, have mercy on us, for laying aside all excuse,
 we sinners offer to Thee as to our Master this supplication: have mercy
 on us.\\

Glory to the Father, and to the Son, and to the Holy Spirit:\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean all paragraphs follows the tag `\prayerheading` should be indent? If yes, just give an enter mark between the tag and the paragraph:

```
\prayerheading{Evening Troparia-Tone 6}

 Have mercy on us, O Lord, have mercy on us, for laying aside all excuse,...
```

If my guess is not correct, then let me know...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you place a blank line or `\par` after `\prayerheading`, it will be part of the paragraph you want to indent.  The easiest way to indent every line is to use `\leftskip`, which must be defined before the start of the paragraph.

Since `center` is implemented using `trivlist`, `\leftskip` has no effect on the `\prayerheading` itself.  Neither does `\vspace` or `\indent`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{framed}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\newcommand{\prayerheading}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
    \scshape\Large\textcolor{black}{#1}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\leftskip=\parindent
\prayerheading{Evening Troparia-Tone 6}
 Have mercy on us, O Lord, have mercy on us, for laying aside all excuse,
 we sinners offer to Thee as to our Master this supplication: have mercy
 on us.

Glory to the Father, and to the Son, and to the Holy Spirit:
\leftskip=0pt

\end{document}
```